# What is Linda McFly eating for breakfast at the end of Back to the Future?

Tags: time-travel, back-to-the-future, food

In the scene at the end of Back to the Future, Marty's siblings are eating breakfast together in the timeline where his family is rich and successful. What is his sister eating for breakfast? It looks like a bowl of meatballs - does this imply that some change Marty made altered history in a way that made meatballs an acceptable breakfast food?

[image]

Comment: Looks like tomatoes to me. The smaller kind.

Comment: The novelisation is no help "*Dave wore an expensive business suit and was reading Forbes magazine; **sister Linda was dressed casually but elegantly as she ate what appeared to be eggs Benedict.** The dining room was equipped with much more expensive furniture than he remembered, the table set with delicate linen.*"

Comment: The shooting script also says eggs benedict. Strange.

Comment: @Plutor - The novel was based on the shooting script.

Comment: It's almost certainly some kind of fruit in a red juice, probably melon balls.

Comment: Whoever wrote the shooting script obviously wasn't aware that in the far flung future of 2015, chickens are extinct and eggs benedict is no longer available.

Answer (score 19):

Based on the similarity of the cropped/blown up image:

[image]

(particularly the red item with apparent white streak, right in the middle)

to this one:

[image]

I'm going to guess she's eating sliced strawberries.

Answer (score -1):

they look like cherry tomatoes to me

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You could make this a better answer by including some additional details, for example that the size matches.

Comment: @max - You could improve this answer by editing it to include an image of some cherry tomatoes as a visual aid.